The program has exited with code 200 (0xc8)
Trying to debug a program from Visual Studio 2022. No exception caught. Program exits with code 200 (0xc8).
Windows Error description:
200 (0xC8): ERROR_RING2SEG_MUST_BE_MOVABLE. The code segment cannot be greater than or equal to 64K.
Windows Application Event Log:
System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): Access is denied
at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()

Was running as Administrator.
Rebuilding, changing configuration did not help.
Restarting VS did not help.
Stopping IIS did not help.
The error went away when the dev machine was restarted.
